# Azure Functions - Function key encryption in transit and making it not visible in headers

Tags: c#, security, encryption, azure-functions, request-headers

The functions hosted in my Function app are consumed by an Client UI application. The functions have Function level authorization. So, a function-key needs to be sent while calling function in the request header or the URL itself. Hence, key is not safe and is exposed while the call is in transit and to whoever uses the client application. How can I make the key not visible in the application?

Answer (score 2):

> 1. How can I make the key not visible in the application?

By not using the key in the front-end. Anything sent from the front-end is visible to the user using it.

> 2. How can I encrypt or make the key safe when the request is travelling to the Function app so it will not intercepted and details of key would not be compromised?

You use HTTPS (TLS) for the connection.

You cannot hold secrets in a front-end UI application.
The app cannot authenticate itself since it is running in an untrusted environment.

The app should in my opinion call either an endpoint that does not require authentication at all or requires the user to authenticate.
With the latter option you then verify the authentication token for the user in your function.

Or you could use IP address filtering that only allows specific users' IP addresses access to the back-end.
This is not 100% secure though since IP addresses can be re-assigned to other people and also degrades the user experience.